# Android Action Bar Up Button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I've got 2 activity's; A.java and B.java.
I want to have an Action Bar Up Button in the B.java, when I execute this code:

> startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
>   finish();

And I create the Up Button in activity B.java with this code:

> ActionBar ab = new ActionBar();
>   ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

And I also set the parentActivityName for activity B in the Android Manifest to:

> android:minSdkVersion="16"
>   ...
>   android:parentActivityName="com.name.appname.A"

My up button appears, but when I click it, the application just finishes himself instead of going back to activity A.java.

I think this is because of the "finish();" when I call activity B, am I right?
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove finish() method

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to `finish()` the activity ? All steps you have provided are correct but instead of specifically finishing it you can try this code. This finishes activity B and will start/resume activity A automatically.

`@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
      case android.R.id.home:
         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
         return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}`

Comment: Yes I want to finish it because when the app goes back to activity A, the data will be updated when A.java appears. Can I use your code for that?

Comment: then add the code i posted above to activity B. This will automatically finish activity B and go to A and over there in activity A you need to handle the updated data in `onResume()`

Comment: Hi, it works! But if I go to activity A from Activity B (through the Up Button) he opens activity A again (a cople of seconds after activity A opens). That's because I've got a timer in activity B and if the time is up, activity B will close and activity A will come to the foreground (so activity B is still running when activity A closes). How can I just close whole activity B when I press the Up Button? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't matter, such a dumb question: finish (); below the NavUtils!